# Unable to parse XML with different namespace

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have a sample XML like this:

```
<Envelope xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
    <Header>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <getNewTokenResponse xmlns="http://abc.examples.com/">
            <return>
                {{session.key}}
            </return>
        </getNewTokenResponse>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

And this code is used to parse it:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
HashMap nsMap = getNameSpaceMap(input);
xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {
    @Override
    public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
        if(nsMap.has(prefix)){
           return nsMap.get(prefix);
        }
        return XMLConstants.NULL_NS_URI;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
});

Node getNewTokenResp = 
     (Node) xpath.evaluate("/Envelope/Body/getNewTokenResponse/return", 
     document, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

It doesn't return the correct value because of no prefix being used for namespace.

Is there any better way to parse this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `/s:Envelope/s:Body/p:getNewTokenResponse/p:return` as XPath expression and supply a namespace context that maps `s` to `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` and `p` to `http://abc.examples.com/`.